# macro variable not being resolved correctly in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS macro like this:

```
%macro test;
proc sql;
SELECT count(*) INTO:Nbr_Obs from table1;
quit;
%put  observations=&Nbr_Obs;
%if &Nbr_Obs=0 %then %do;
proc sql;
  drop table table1 ;
quit;
%end;
%mend;
```

Neither the %put statement is showing up in the log, and the 'if' condition is always evaluating to true. How can I resolve this?

EDIT: This is what I see in log:

```
MPRINT(TEST):   proc sql;
MPRINT(TEST):   SELECT count(*) INTO:Nbr_Obs from TABLE1;
MPRINT(TEST):   quit;
observations=
...
...
```

And after this, it shows that SQL is executing. So it seems that the PU T statement is executing before the SQL?

Comment: Did you call the macro?  The code you posted just defines it. What do you see in the SAS log?  Does the dataset TABLE1 exist?

Comment: In the SAS log, I see that the table is dropped regardless of nbr_obs.

Comment: If the table is 0, does the macro variable get created? I thought it didn't for some reason.

Comment: Well, the table has a lot of rows, so nbr_obs should not be equal to 0

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try adding a line before the `SELECT` statement to set `NBR_OBS` to some default value. Try starting a new SAS session. Perhaps you have SAS confused?

Comment: Or turn on options MPRINT and show your log. If the log shows the SQL steps executing but does not show the results of your %PUT statement, that would be very odd.

Comment: also suggest add %local nbr_obs;

Comment: Can you see my EDIT?

Comment: What comes next in the log?  Is there MPRINT showing the second SQL step?  I would expect not. What makes you think the %if is always evaluating to true? Suggest you turn on options MLOGIC to check that.

Comment: Are you using SAS UE or a full version of SAS, if so what version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a best practise to strip leading and trailing blanks from macro variables created using INTO clause, this is the reason for incorrect comparison. Please modify as below,

```
%macro test;  

   proc sql;
     SELECT count(*) INTO:Nbr_Obs 
     from table1;
   quit;  

   %let Nbr_Obs=&Nbr_Obs; * Strips blanks;  
   %put  observations=&Nbr_Obs;  

   %if &Nbr_Obs=0 %then %do;  
     proc sql;  
       drop table table1 ;  
     quit;  

   %end;  

%mend;
```

Comment: You can use the TRIMMED option in PROC SQL to avoid the %let statement, in SAS 9.3+ http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1tupenuhmu1j0n19d3curl9igt4.htm

Comment: Agree that trimming blanks from macro vars is a good idea, but it isn't (or at least shouldn't be) the cause of Victor's problem.  The %if statement implied %eval ignores leading and trailing blanks.  So `%if           0      =0 %then %do;` would be true, regardless of number of blanks.  I agree with Tom, the original macro produces the intended result when I run it.  Would be helpful to see full log from a batch submit of an example showing unexpected result (with MPRINT and MLOGIC).  Otherwise, I think Victor may have misunderstood the results, or had a corrupted SAS session.

Answer (score 0):

If your code previously failed, SAS sets `SYNTAXCHECK` option and `OBS=0`. This means the SQL statements are read and checked for syntax but not *actually* executed. That's why they appear in the `MPRINT` output.

Reset the system options using:

`OPTIONS NOSYNTAXCHECK OBS=MAX;`

and try again.